# Error on installing RISCV toolchain on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: riscv, chisel

I am trying to install riscv-toolchain on ubuntu 20.10. I got the error while .buidl.sh executes

Configuring project riscv-isa-sim
Building project riscv-isa-sim

```
   ./fesvr/dtm.cc: In member function ‘uint32_t dtm_t::get_xlen()’:
   ../fesvr/dtm.cc:488:16: error: ‘runtime_error’ is not a member of ‘std’
  488 |     throw std::runtime_error("FESVR DTM Does not support 128-bit");
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../fesvr/dtm.cc:505:14: error: ‘runtime_error’ is not a member of ‘std’
  505 |   throw std::runtime_error("FESVR DTM can't determine XLEN. Aborting");
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../fesvr/dtm.cc:506:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  506 | }
      | ^
```

Answer (score 1):

std::runtime_error is defined in stdexcept. normally you are missing `#include <stdexcept>`. However normally, this modification was done in the riscv-isa-sim 7 months ago. you are probably not using the last version.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It worked I downloaded from [link](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools) . Is there other clones with updated one.

Comment: you are welcome. however i don't understand your question. can you be more explicit?

Comment: that repo essentially calls other tools and passes along the ideal build script to each. i had similar issues as well including the one you stated. I tried this out recently and it did not compile properly.

Comment: what do you mean by not compiling properly. I compiled it under ubuntu 18.04 with the toolchain from https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain . the only thing broken is the riscv-tests because of multiple definition but the simulator and openocd compile fine.